# How to load thumbnail from custom directory?

Tags: android, thumbnails, fetch

I have searched a lot but I got samples to fetch thumbnail from an `Url` or from `Http`,
but I actually need to get thumbnail of an image from my own directory on `sdcard` withot accesing the `Android` default thumbnail directory, thats is I need to fetch a thumbnail of an image from 
`mnt/sdcard/myown/1.png`

Can anybody help for this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have also looked on ImageLoade.jar, and universal image loader, but i cant get any of this requirment

Answer (score 0):

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/mnt/sdcard"

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + PATH_TO_IMAGE;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
```

Comment: hi @Dmytro Danylyk can u say me how to bring an image onclick on button i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

}

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/myown/1.png";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

your layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Image" />

</LinearLayout>
```